# send session variable to another php page that is never loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

index page recieves the session variables from login page. I want this session variable to be sent to another php page withour any action from the user. A table is created and filled with data using the script.js file. The script.js file has ajax calls to dbmanipulate.php file. dbmanipulate.php interacts with the database. now is there anyway to send the php session variable from index.php to dbmanipulate.php 
the only page that the user loads is index.php and he is shown with a table that is produced dynamically.

my index.php page after edits:

```
        <?php
        session_start();
        $fname=$_SESSION['mail'];
        ?>

        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <title>Addressbook</title>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>





 <script type="text/javascript">

 function myFunction () {


$.ajax({
     url:"DbManipulate.php",
              type:"POST",
              data:"<?php echo $fname ?>"

               });

   }

   </script>            
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="crudstyle.css" />

        </head>
        <body onload="myFunction()" bg color="">

            <div id="hidden_form_container" style="display:none;"></div>

        <div id="mhead"><h2>Your Adressbook</h2></div>
        <div id="note"> <span> your addressbook is connected to our servers :) </span></div>
        <?php
        echo $fname;

        ?>
        <table id='demoajax' cellspacing="0">
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: you need to define session_start() in your DbManipulate1.php.

Comment: session start wont work as dbmanipulate file is not accesed via index. it would work of there was a connected flow between them

Comment: simply, use hidden iframe!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
 $.ajax({
 var session_data = <?php $_SESSION['mail'] ?>;
 url:"DbManipulate1.php",
     type:"POST",
     data:"{actionfunction:showData,session_data:session_data"},
     cache: false,
     success: function(response){

      $('#demoajax').html(response);
          createInput();
      }
});
```

> try this :)

Comment: and where am i to implement it? in index.php?

Comment: this way you can access your session variable from your function, which function will called via this ajax

sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Inside your function which called by ajax, just use this code print_r($_POST) and debug it in your browser console, your will shown that your session value is there.

Answer (score 0):

May be cheat around a little bit?
put this in to the php file instead of including the .js file.

```
    <script>
  $(function(){
        $.ajax({
                url:"DbManipulate1.php?mail=<?php echo $_SESSION['mail']; ?>",
                type:"POST",
                data:"actionfunction=showData",
                cache: false,
              success: function(response){

                    $('#demoajax').html(response);
                 createInput();

                                         }
               });
   </script>
```

and get the variable using $_GET['mail'] on the other page.

---

edit:
try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
 url:"DbManipulate.php",
          type:"POST",
          data:"mail=<?php echo $fname ?>"

           });
}
```

and use $_POST['mail'] on the other page.And don't put on_load in body tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are some subtleties in different hosts. Try to call a session variable in that file without declaring it just for the transition without AJAX. If it was produced then everything should work, if not then ask your hosting provider if you do not need to specify the path to session in php.ini. Further check encoding the files themselves that they are UTF-8 without BOM.

Since you run the files on one server session variable does not necessarily send POST means it should be easily retrieved using the session_start () at the beginning of the file ...